# Joomla change RSMonials Emal content

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using RSMonials for the testimonials in one of my website. I've an option to change the email body in the language file called "**RSM_EMAIL_ADMIN_BODY**". This is nice, but it would be great if there is an option to append the newly created testimonial to the email body.

For example, If a new testimonial is created like "test testimonial", it should also be sent along with the email. Is this possible? Or anyother ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the option is currently not available with `RSMonials` right now. I contacted the `RSMonials` support team and they confirmed the same.